# ThreadLocal and Memory usage

Tags: java, multithreading, memory

ThreadLocal is created to have a separate copy of objects to operate on in a threadsafe manner.

This means that the number of objects in process will increase as number of threads.
This because, each thread will create its own copy of ThreadLocals.

- Does it not increase the memory requirement of a process ?

Comment: Sure does. When the threads terminate, the objects disappear.

Comment: ... Of course, more objects means more memory; this is self-evident.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it just asks confirmation of an evidence.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to imply that it is `ThreadLocal`s which are a specific culprit which increases memory usage, but in fact your question is not particularly related to `ThreadLocal`s *per se*. In the situation you describe, they are merely some object which have been allocated at some point and will go unreacheable when the thread dies at the latest.

Answer (score 1):

The [amount of memory](http://javaguru.fi/blog/-/blogs/why-is-my-java-process-taking-more-memory-than-i-gave-it-) a process takes in java depends on:

- Objects
- Classes
- Threads
- Native data structures
- Native code

The memory consumption associated with each item varies across applications, runtime environments and platforms.  So how do you calculate the total memory? Well, it's not really all that easy to get accurate number because you have little control over the native part. The only parts you can really control is the amount of heap -Xmx, memory consumed by classes -XX:MaxPermSize and thread stack -Xss which controls the amount of memory each thread takes. Be careful when adjusting stack size as too low size will cause StackOverflow exceptions and your application won't work correctly. So the formula is:

```
(-Xmx) + (-XX:MaxPermSize) + numberofthreads * (-Xss) + Other mem
```

So clearly the amount of memory a process takes would increase as the number of threads increases. 
Your question does not seems to be about ThreadLocals,its rather about the thread in general.