# How does memory usage of thread_local scale with number of threads?

Tags: c++, c, thread-local-storage

I presume C/C++ standards do not say anything about complexity so I am curious about specific implementations (I presume they all have same behavior).

Assume I have the following C++ function.

```
void fn() {
    thread_local char arr[1024*1024]{};
    // do something with arr
}
```

And my program has 80 threads, 47 of them at least once run `fn()`.

Does the memory usage of my program grows around 47 times some constant, 80 times some constant, or is there some other formula for this?

note: there is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17970078/threadlocal-and-memory-usage) Java question that got closed for some reason, but IDK if Java uses same primitives as C/C++.

Comment: This is implementation-defined, and depends on the application as well. On operating system that use demand paging and overcommits, the operating system will not try to find the memory for the array until there's a page fault when trying to access it. But, on other operating system each newly created thread must pony up for all of its local memory, when the thread starts.

Comment: If you think you need thread local -- you don't.

Comment: Do you have a specific implementation in mind? gcc, clang, msvc, etc?

Comment: 'Thread local' is globals for threads:(

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili I assume they all use same underlying mechanism, but if not clang, gcc msvc, on Win and Linux.

Comment: @YakovGalka *If you think you need thread local -- you don't*  Well, if you think you need C++, you don't.  Just use assembler...

Comment: @AndrewHenle: you are missing the point. Thread-local is a hack for when somebody forgets to pass their context down the call stack. And there's nothing C++ specific about it. There are some legit historical reasons to use it (when converting legacy code to multi-threaded; e.g. `errno` and OpenGL context). However, if the OP introduces 1MB of TLS they are doing it wrong.

Comment: @YakovGalka I have seen people use it to have thread_local vector or something so they can reuse it across function calls, without locks... ugly but in theory it might be faster than allocating vector every call or having a mutex around shared static vector... not saying it is nice, that is what I saw...

Comment: @YakovGalka No, ***you*** missed the point.  Thread-local is a **tool** to be used or not to be used.  Just like C++ - a hack for those who forgot how to write assembler.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl you don't need locks nor thread locals for that. Change your function to `void fn(char buf[1024*1024])` (or similar) and have the caller allocate the buffer once per multiple calls. You may need to refactor a little bit, but you gain the explicit control over the lifetime of that buffer, thus circumventing the vague semantics of thread locals. Thread locals are bad for a variety of reasons, and in some situations (dynamic libraries) they simply don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely largely implementation dependant though you can verify the behaviour of your implementation fairly easily. For example running the following program on windows (using a debug visual studio build to avoid optimisations removing the unused code):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <thread>

struct Foo
{
    std::array<char, 1'000'000'000> data;
};

void bar()
{
    thread_local Foo foo;
    for (int i = 0; i < foo.data.size(); i++)
    {
        foo.data[i] = i;
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1000));
}

int main()
{
    std::thread thread1([]
    {
        bar();
    });

    std::thread thread2([]
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1000));
    });

    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();
}
```

Uses 3GB of memory (1GB for the two threads and 1GB for the main thread). Removing `thread2` drops the memory usage to 2GB. On Linux this behaviour is likely to be different as it has over allocation and unused memory pages are not allocated until they're used.

You can avoid this by using smart pointers to only allocate the memory when its actually used, for example changing `bar` to:

```
void bar()
{
    thread_local std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo = std::make_unique<Foo>();
    for (int i = 0; i < foo->data.size(); i++)
    {
        foo->data[i] = i;
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1000));
}
```

Reduces the memory usage to 1GB as only `thread1` actually allocates the large array, `thread2` and the main thread only have to store the `unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 3):

According to the `C++11` Standard:

> **3.7.2** *Thread storage duration* **[** basic.stc.thread **]**
>
> **1** All variables declared with the thread_local keyword have thread storage duration. The storage for these
> entities shall last for the duration of the thread in which they are created. There is a distinct object or
> reference per thread, and use of the declared name refers to the entity associated with the current thread.
>
> **2** A variable with thread storage duration shall be initialized before its first odr-use (3.2) and, if constructed,
> shall be destroyed on thread exit.

It says, *"The storage for these entities shall last for the duration of the thread in which they are created.".* So, to my reading, the memory must be allocated for all of the threads.

However, they are only *initialized* and *destructed* if they are used: *"A variable with thread storage duration shall be initialized before its first odr-use (3.2) and, if constructed, shall be destroyed on thread exit".*